# Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword INSERT at [11:1] error in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword INSERT at [11:1] error in bigquery

```
create table percentpopulationvaccinated
(
    continent string,
    Location string,
    Date datetime,
    population numeric,
    new_vaccinations numeric,
    peoplevaccinated numeric
)

insert into percentpopulationvaccinated 
    select 
        dea.continent, dea.location, dea.date, dea.population,  
        new_vaccinations,
        sum(vac.new_vaccinations) over (partition by dea.location order by dea.location, dea.date) as peoplevaccinated
    from 
        my-protfolio-324718.sql_code.covid_deaths dea
    join 
        my-protfolio-324718.sql_code.covid_vac vac on dea.location = vac.location
                                                   and dea.date = vac.date

select 
    *,
    (peoplevaccinated / population) * 100
from 
    percentpopulationvaccinated
```

Comment: you have a script with two statements (create and insert). all statements must be separated by `;` , so add it between `insert` and preceding `)` and you should be fine till potentially next/another error :o)

Answer (score 0):

The create table is one query, insert into is the second and finally the third is the select. In bigquery you should separate them using a `;` so the interpreter can run every step in order.